# ctype functions(isalpha, isdigit) show wrong values in c++

Tags: c++

This is a testing code of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ctype.h"
using std::cout;

int main(){
    cout << "Welcome to the program: ";
    cout << "\n" << "Let's see if the value of \'x\' is digital: ";
    int x = 5;
    cout << isdigit(x);
    
    cout << "\n" << "Let's see if the value of \'i\' is alphabetical: ";
    char i = 'i';
    cout << isalpha(i);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

> Welcome to the program:
>
> Let's see if the value of 'x' is digital: 0
>
> Let's see if the value of 'i' is alphabetical: 2

**Values like 2 or 0 while both of them are true?
shouldn't it be just 0 or 1 values shown in the results?**
*Note: I didn't change the values with 'enum' or '#define' in the global variable section.*

Comment: 5 is not the same thing as '5'

Comment: these functions may give any non-zero value for the "true" case

Answer (score 6):

The `isXXX()` functions will return an integer representing a true or false value. Given that zero is false and anything else is true, two is a perfectly acceptable return value.

The reason you're getting a false value for `isdigit(5)` is because that function takes a *character* and tells you whether it's a digit. While `'5'` may be a digit character, `5` is most likely *not.*

C++ defers to C for these functions since they're part of the `cctype` header. The relevant portion of the standard (`C99 7.4`) states:

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`.
>
> The functions in this subclause return nonzero (true) if and only if the value of the argument `c` conforms to that in the description of the function.

Generally, in C, and in C++ C-legacy functions <sup>(a)</sup>, you should never be comparing a truth value against a fixed true/false value. Since it treats zero as false, everything else as true, the correct way to do it would be something like:

```
cout << "It " << (isdigit(x) ? "is" : "isn't") << " a digit";
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is usually a good rule to follow, even for C++ `bool` comparisons (and other languages) where it *has* to be true or false.

If a boolean value or function is properly named (and it *should* be), the right way to do it is:

```
if (! errorOccurred) ...
if (isComplete) ...
if (isdigit(myChar)) ...
```

That's because, using *reductio ad absurdum*, the expression `boolVal == TRUE` is simply *another* boolean value, so where do you stop?

```
if (isComplete == TRUE) ...
if ((isComplete == TRUE) == TRUE) ...
if (((isComplete == TRUE) == TRUE) == TRUE) ...
if ((((isComplete == TRUE) == TRUE) == TRUE) == TRUE)...
```

And so on, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: *you should never be comparing a truth value against a fixed true/false value* unless you know that a function returns a `bool`.

Comment: @RSahu, no C or C++ C-legacy functions return a `bool`. In any case, it's a good rule to follow even for C++. I will clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see your point. It may be a personal preference, but I do prefer to use `if ( true == isSomePredicate(...) )`.

Comment: here as well :D You're even quoting that part of the standard

Answer (score 2):

No, `isalpha` and `isdigit` do not return a bool, nor are they required to return `1`. They're specified to return a **non-zero** value if the predicate is satisfied, zero otherwise.